# Vertx-ignite 3.4.2 doesn't work with Ignite 2.0.0

Tags: java, cluster-computing, ignite, vert.x

I'm trying to use Ignite as a Cluster Manager with Vert.x but I have the error below, did anyone have this error before ?

I use Vertx 3.4.2 and Apache Ignite 2.0.0. They should work together regarding the official vertx-ignite module site, so I think I'm doing something wrong.

Thank to anyone who could help me.

Best regards

```
[10:26:06] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=1.7GB]
juil. 18, 2017 10:26:06 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
INFOS: Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=1.7GB]
juil. 18, 2017 10:26:06 AM io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl
GRAVE: Failed to join cluster
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.ignite.configuration.CollectionConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(Lorg/apache/ignite/cache/CacheAtomicityMode;)V
    at io.vertx.spi.cluster.ignite.IgniteClusterManager.lambda$join$5(IgniteClusterManager.java:229)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:271)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.lambda$new$0(TaskQueue.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: OK, my fault, I wasn't looking the right version of vertx-ignite, it's still in V1.9 of Ignite.

Answer (score 1):

In next version 3.5.0 will be added support for ignite 2.0:

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-ignite/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I'm impatient to discover the next release 3.5.0 of Vert.x! Do you know when it will be released?